# Random variables are determined by their characteristic functions proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity

[image]

From the line $F_Y(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty} F_y(t_n)$, here the author is assuming that $t$ is not a continuity point of $F_Y$, and is being approximated by continuity points $t_n$, and the result holds as $F_Y$ is right continuous - but the approximation of $t_n \downarrow t$ for every discontinuity point only holds if there are countable many discontinuity points surely - and  I don't see how we know that we have a countable amount of discontinuity points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any distribution function $F$ is *monotone non-decreasing*, bounded above by $1$ and below by $0$ and right continuous. Any such function

1. may only have jump discontinuities,
2. may only have at most countably many discontinuities.

Comment: I don't follow exactly why it may only have jump discontinuities and why that means at most countably many discontinuities (what other continuities do we have other than jump?). What I was thinking was, at every discontinuity point $F(x)$ we can draw an interval for some $\delta > 0$, say $I_x = (F(x - \delta), F(x + \delta))$, since there will be a rational number in this interval, and the rationals and countable, we have at most a countable no. of discontinuities. I don't see how this uses your 1. or 2. though (or if $F$ is increasing)

Comment: You are using that $F$ is increasing, in order to ensure that the rationals that you pick are different. Otherwise the fact that the rationals are countable cannot be exploited. The other form of discontinuities is essential discontinuities.

Comment: Moreover monotonicity ensures (roughly) that left and right one-sided limits exist, so that any discontinuity cannot be essential discontinuity. Can you follow it now?

Comment: Thanks, I follow what I wrote in my previous comment, and I understand now that there will only be jump discontinuities - but I don't see how you used that to immediately conclude that there will be at most countably many. Additionally, if $F$ was not bounded, surely it would still hold?

Comment: Yes, you do not need that $F$ is bounded for this. To conclude was left to you, which is better or not? And you almost did it in your comment - except that you did not use the monotonicity of $F$ to ensure that the rationals are different and hence countably many.

Comment: Ah OK, I thought it was somehow immediate. Thanks, I follow now.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, you solved it by yourself!